# how to write a clean code without using enums

Tags: java, java-8

I have an enum as below

```
public enum ProductType{

 P1("Pone")
 P2("Ptwo")

 public String value;

  public String getValue(){
      return value;
  } 

 public Product fromValue(Brand b){
     if(b.equals("A")){
         return P1;
     else
         return P2
     }
}
```

And here is how i use it

```
Class ABC{

        public String getProductName(Brand b){
           return ProductType.fromValue(b).getName();
      }
}
```

How can I achieve the same without using an ENUM. I want to be able to return ProductName from brand without using ENUM

Comment: I'd be surprised if the code snippet you gave actually compiled, please edit your question so that we can understand what you're asking for, read this article on how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Why do you hate enums?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. Letting misplaced `{` and `}` aside, in the line `if(b.equals("A"))`, you are checking whether an instance of `Brand` is equal to an instance of `String`, which will always be `false`. But of course, you can do exactly the same without the `ProductType` class: `public String getProductName(Brand b){ return b.equals("A")? "Pone": "Ptwo"; }`

Answer (score 0):

It's not clear why you're trying to avoid enums, but here's an equivalent pre-Java-5 version. Your code is riddled with errors, so I've made some assumptions and corrections:

```
public class ProductType {
    public static final ProductType P1 = new ProductType("Pone");
    public static final ProductType P2 = new ProductType("Ptwo");

    private final String value;

    private Product(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.value;
    }

    public ProductType fromValue(String value) {
        return value.equals(P1.value) ? P1
               value.equals(P2.value) ? P2 : null;
    }
}
```

Comment: I do not want to create object ProductType, but use a translator maybe?

Comment: Please clarify what you're trying to do and why.